# SQL - Inserting into table with concatenation with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I need to insert data into a table with a concatenation depending on the value of one of the columns. E.g.

**Table A**:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| rowid | objectIdA | objectIdB |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  1    |         1 |         2 | 
|  2    |         1 |      null | 
|  3    |         2 |         4 | 
|  4    |         5 |      null | 
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

Would result in **Table B**:

```
+-------+-----------+
| rowid | concatCol | 
+-------+-----------+
|  1    |      1_2  |
|  2    |      1    | 
|  3    |      2_4  |
|  4    |      5    |
+-------+-----------+
```

So basically concatenate with an underscore if one of the columns isn't null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about?

```
INSERT INTO tableB(rowid, concatCol)
SELECT
    rowid,
    objectIdA + CASE WHEN objectIDB IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '_' + objectIDB END 
FROM
    TableA
```

Comment: +1, but for Oracle I think you need || instead of +?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your database system and programming language. A pure SQL solution can get pretty ugly (especially if you need to support update and insert).

```
INSERT INTO tableB(rowid, concatCol)
    (SELECT rowid, objectIdA+'_'+objectIDB FROM tableA)
```

Would work if + is the concatenation operation (Oracle uses `||` I think) and if the second table is empty (and if rowid is actually insertable). If the columns are nullable you can use your RDBMS function for `CASE` to differentiate between the case you need to add second row and separator or skip both.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Some additional information:
I'm using SQL Server
If objectIDB is null or empty I don't want the underscore in the result (which I believe the solution above would give)

Comment: Yes please provide additional information @user1562497

Answer (score 0):

Try,
Suppose your colunm is integer Datatype

```
select rowid,cast(objectIdA as varchar(10)) + case when objectIdB is null then '' else '_'+
             cast(objectIdB as varchar(10)) end
from tab1
```